# Is there a way to show Icon in Xamarin.Forms Shell top tab?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to develop a UI using Xamarin.Forms (Shell Navigation). I have bottom tabs and in each bottom tab there are several top tabs. I can able to show bottom tab Icons but the top tab icons are not shown (invisible). However, the text is visible.

I already tried to set `Icon="image.png"` for top tabs as I did for bottom tabs. Still the icons on top tabs are not visible.

Part of my XAML code:

```
<TabBar>
        <Tab Title="Browse" Icon="tab_feed.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="About" Icon="tab_about.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Title="Test 2" Icon="tab_others.png">
            <ShellContent Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False" Title="abt" Icon="tab_about.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
            <ShellContent Title="fed" Icon="tab_feed.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
        </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

The Icons defined in `ShellContent` are not visible (titles are visible though).

Please provide any direction or document to attain this.

Comment: Bottom tabs can have images whereas when they are top-aligned you cannot do that you cannot add icons there but in case if you want to then in that case you might have to create renderer's for shell tabs!